# Angular 4 With visual studio 2017 Environment

Tags: angular, webpack, visual-studio-2017

I am trying my hand at the Angular 4 , so far I like it, I am just at a loss when it comes to the tooling in VS 2017. I know I can use the command line tools, however I would like to stay in visual studio! I got an application working and I can launch and debug using visual studio what I am trying to figure out is how to switch my build - for example in a C# solution I can switch the build from debug to release and do an IF DEBUG, what is the equivalent way of doing that for angular? Has anyone figured how to connect the build mode to the environment variable for angular using visual studio.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1231 could sound pretty good for you

Answer (score 0):

Everything you'll want to do can be done from the terminal inside of VS by leveraging the webpack config and setting up build scripts.

I would suggest taking a dive into webpack and understanding how it works, and what you can do with it. There's a good 30 minute intro here: https://webpack.academy/courses

You can setup development builds using webpack-dev-server that do hot module replacement for live updates to your running code on save (automatic incremental rebuilds), and production builds that uglify, minify and transpile your code for deployment.